# Построить intent для открытия google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

Здравствуйте,

есть задача, открыть из моего приложения, приложение карт google с отображение точки направления и моего местоположения.

И собственно вопрос как открыть чтобы google maps открылась с zoom таким, чтобы было видно как и мою локацию так и точку назначения?

Как сейчас делаю я и это не работает:

```
    private void startMaps(String fields) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(fields, 1);
                Address a = address.get(0);
                String uri =  String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"geo:%f , %f?q=%s", a.getLatitude(), a.getLongitude(),  "my+location");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте так: `http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=60.344,64.34&daddr=my+location`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к сожалению, не поддалось. Решил, что проще модуль карт в приложение внедрить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял, что такое в принципе без задержек не получиться сделать, сделал встроенный Fragment карт и в нем уже определяю локацию и делаю zoom камеры по двум точкам с padding.